# tensorflow-syntaxnet: Where are sentence_pb2 and gen_parser_ops?

Tags: python, tensorflow, syntaxnet

I cannot import these two python files from syntaxnet and I cannot find them either. Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Thanks!

from syntaxnet.ops import gen_parser_ops
from syntaxnet import sentence_pb2

Comment: The Syntaxnet model is not a Python library to be imported: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/148. Solution seems to be to make subprocess calls from Python to it after it is built

Comment: Follow instructions here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/syntaxnet#installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those two are imported in `syntaxnet/syntaxnet/conll2tree.py`. You can get their locations by adding lines like below in `conll2tree.py`:

```
import os
print os.path.realpath(gen_parser_ops.__file__)
```

and then run the `demo.sh` as in the installation guide.